# How to change the color of my navigation bar

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee, jsf-2, primefaces

Instead of a common navigation bar i use a primefaces tool called [dock](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-labs/ui/dock.jsf). 
I want to change its background color, i don't want the grey that comes by default.
But i am confused:

I don't know what i should do.

Should i create some .css? If so, how i pass it to the component?

Do i need to hack the component source code in someway to achieve this?If so how can i change just what interests me without harming the component?

Could someone give me some tips how can i achieve my goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the top bar on the page link is pointing to. you need to override following classes

`ui-dock-top ui-widget` & `ui-dock-item-top`

add style `background-color:somevalue` to change the color

Comment: Where can i find those classes(.css)? Where are those css located how i edit them?

Comment: you can use [firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) to get the css class name, and you need to provide your own css class with that name to override the one provided from framework

Comment: I understand. I never used firebug to edit css files. Will the changes remain? That css file is probably located inside the primefaces .jar file

Comment: use firebug just to know the class name, and create a css file overriding the default implementation from the framework

Comment: Ok i understand. But then how i replace then my css with the one on the framework. Should i remove the old one from the .jar file and then insert the new one?(I am not really sure what do you mean with override)

Comment: by override I mean: include a css file in your page.having a class with the same name, so that while rendering it will override the style

Comment: I understand, what it really matters is not how i can call the file, but how i call the class inside it. I will try that.

Comment: What i wanted to say is that i am creating my own .css file(not important its name) and inside it i override the classes: `ui-dock-top` `ui-widget` & `ui-dock-item-top` The important thing is that the class names match correctly.